# Rails - How can I remove the :3000 from the URL in rails thin server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thin

I have binded my rails thin server to a local IP. which I have given the domain name as project1. But when I am changing the hostname to project1 sometimes it goes to project1:3000. How can I remove the :3000 from the URL?

Comment: if you're hosting on a non-standard port, then the port **MUST** be there. otherwise the browser will simply use the default 80/443 ones. YOu can't magically make `http://example.com` point at port 8000, because that's not the default.

Comment: Do you want to do that in development? if this is the deployed version of ur app, you should run your application in "production" mode.

Comment: I have also tried to run the server in production mode. But the port number is present in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Web standards are:

- http is port 80.
- https is port 443.

When you go to http://stackoverflow.com, it is the same as http://stackoverflow.com:80 or https://www.google.com is the same as https://www.google.com:443

So, the :3000 at the end of the url is the port where your development server is pointing, this is normal behavior for web development. All modern frameworks will serve up the development site on a different port, 3000 being the most common. This is done for a lot of reasons, two good ones are.

1. Don't need to change any permission to run on port 3000, like you do if you want to run on 80, and you don't need to us an ssl certificate if you run on 443.
2. You can tell when you are in development.

You are trying to do something you shouldn't. If you haven't used the correct helper methods to build your links in rails you could run into some issue.

Now that you know why you shouldn't do it. You can just change the port in the rails server command like this `rails server -b THEIPYOUWANTTOUSE -p 80`. You will have to have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.You need proxy server, because rails have their app server lika thin, puma, rack and you need server that will accept requests to your IP (nginx, apache) and give them to rails server. There is a lot of guides how to deploy rails app in production mode. Try [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) guide or [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) . This will help you run your application in production mode.